# PS: Retrieve output from executable stream (websocat)

Tags: powershell, websocket

I've been searching a long time now for clues on how to work with websocat (https://github.com/vi/websocat) in Powershell.

**What I want to do is the following - AS SIMPLE AS POSSIBLE!**

1. Connect to websocket server
2. Send a text command
3. Retrieve the immediate output from the server responding to that particular command
4. Disconnect from the websocket server

I've tried to wrap my head around it to make it as simple as possible.

`Write-Output '<command>' | websocat ws://myserver.com | Out-Default`

This obviously doesn't work, its at best pseudocode but that's because im poor at powershell.

Would be amazing to get some clues on how to go about!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/besimorhino/powercat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what websocat is or ever had a reason to go look for it. Yet, this is not how you run external exe / cmd fom PowerShell. Running exe from PowerShell is a common an well documented use case, with a plethora of articles on the topic all of the web. One just has to search for it. In most cases it's just a matter of using the call operator on the exe directly.

```
& 'websocat' 'ws://myserver.com' 'some command(s)'
```

See the following:

[PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

[Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)

[Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)

[Using Windows PowerShell to run old command line tools (and their weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)

[Execution of external commands in PowerShell done right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right/)

Capturing output from an external command, depends on if the command supports the expected streams and can use the redirects (see the help files) ...

[about_Redirection | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

```
# get function / cmdlet details
# (Get-Command -Name about_Redirection).Parameters
Get-help -Name about_Redirection -Full
Get-help -Name about_Redirection -Online
Get-help -Name about_Redirection -Examples

  *>&1      Sends all output types     Test-Output *>> Test-Output.txt
            (*) to the success output  Test-Output *>&1      
            stream.  

  2>&1      Sends errors (2) and       Get-Process none, Powershell 2>&1
            success output (1) 
            to the success 
            output stream.
```

... or the exe has to provides a way to write to a file that you can read back later. Again, there are lots of guidance on this as well and folks who provide pre-built scripts / tools to assist with this type of thing.

Example:
[Capture output from command line tools with PowerShell](https://blog.ctglobalservices.com/powershell/rja/capture-output-from-command-line-tools-with-powershell/)

If the tool in question requires UI automation to work, then that is a different matter altogether. You can use PowerShell and SendKeys method ...

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'telnet.exe' -ArgumentList 'Some IPA or URL' '-f E:\Temp\Log.txt'
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
$SendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]
$sendkeys::SendWait('Some Command')
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("exit{ENTER}")
```

... or you can use a purpose built tool like Selenium, AutoIT, etc.

Comment: Perhaps if you listened to your first sentence, which is "I never looked up socat..." you would have better understood the question, which is how to replicate the functionality of socat using powershell commands. Socat opens an arbitrary port at a given URI, and outputs any input recieved to it to the standard stream. Which had you done a cursory search for socat, you would have figured out.

Comment: How is your comment helpful, and why did you make it since the OP, accepted my answer as a resolution? So, no need for me to look it up. I am not going to try a figure out or read up one every possible tool/thingy that someone else knows or is using. If you choose to, that's your thing. How do you know I did not look it up later? You don't, so again, don't make assumptions that you have no way of 100% validating. Unless you are providing a better answer, you really should not comment on an accepted one.